# fputs(text, filePtr) returning only the first character of an LPARAM from SendMessage instead of the whole string

Tags: c, winapi

I am writing a WIN32API C program using the Edit_SetText and Edit_GetText macros from windowsx.h header file and SendMessage to save from an edit text box to a file using fputs. The Edit_SetText gets the content of the scan barcode buffer (an LPTSTR) and saves to the edit text box handle. Besides displaying the buffer contents in the edit textbox, I also want to save to file. I used SendMessage and Edit_GetText to retrieve the LPSTR. SendMessage gives me an LPARAM called text.

I use Edit_GetText to retrieve the contents of the textbox into text1 (see code below). Before I save to file using fputs, I display the buffer contents in message boxes to ensure the full barcode is captured. However, when I reopen the text file, I find that fputs is only saving the first character instead of the whole barcode string that is displayed in the message box. How do I save the complete string rather than just the first character of that string? Why is trimming everything except the first character? Here is my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

//Variables
char text[30];
char text1[30];
FILE * fPtr;
char text[60];
HWND hctl_data;

//Open text file for write
fPtr = fopen("barcodedata.txt", "w");

//Get edit textbox handle (IDC_EDIT_DATA)
hctl_data = GetDlgItem(hwnd,IDC_EDIT_DATA);

//Retrieve scan buffer contents and display in edit text box
Edit_SetText(hctl_data, (LPTSTR)SCNBUF_GETDATA(lpScanBuffer));

//SendMessage retrieves from the edit textbox handle to text
SendMessage(hctl_data, WM_GETTEXT, 20, (LPARAM)text);

//Another way to retrieve from the edit textbox handle to a variable, text1
Edit_GetText(hctl_data, &text1, 20);

//Show in message box that the full barcode string is captured (19 characters in length)
MessageBox(0, text, TEXT("InfoA"), MB_OK);
MessageBox(0, text1, TEXT("InfoB"), MB_OK);

//Now save text and text1 to a text file using fputs (or frintf)
fputs(text, fPtr);
fputs(text1, fPtr);

//close file
fclose(fPtr);
```

Comment: Try to use [`_wfopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019) and  [`fputws`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fputs-fputws?view=vs-2019) with unicode string.

Comment: It worked! Thanks Drake!

Answer (score 1):

Usually the Unicode version of an ANSI character is to add a `\0` after the source byte.
such as:

`L"ABC"` <==> `"A\0B\0C\0"`

When we use a multibyte version of the API and pass a wide byte string, `\0` between the charactors is usually interpreted as a string terminator. That's the reason that only the first character is displayed.

Solution:

```
#define UNICODE 1
#define _UNICODE 1
```

`char[]` => `wchar_t[]`;

`fopen("barcodedata.txt", "w");`  => `_tfopen(TEXT("barcodedata.txt"), TEXT("w"))`;

`fputs`  => `_fputts`;

We should pay more attention when we are using mixed multibyte and wide byte functions. Or, it is recommend that we should use a wide byte version for all the context.

Comment: I don't recommend TCHAR. That was useful when you. We're targeting Windows 98. You should be using wchar_t explicitly.

Comment: Hi,@Ezani if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Wonderful! Wonderful! Wonderful Drake Wu! THANKS! Yup..I'm programming for the Motorola MC55A PDA which is a 20-year old technology (because someone invested substantial millions in buying 2,000 units of it and bound my contract to use it). Had to get out my Visual Studio 2008 Pro and Windows CE 5.0 SDK and 6.0. I mentioned the advantages of Android Studio + barcode-reading handphones but got shot down.  :-)